# Robust clustering of standard errors mixed autoregressive models

Tags: mixed-model, stata, multilevel-analysis, robust-standard-error

I have a panel data of the format

```
| age.months | app_id | rank_category | promoted | avg_monthly_rating |...
```

I am using xtmixed where level 2 is app_id. My primary regressor of interest :

```
i.promoted#i.rank_category
```

changes at rank_category level. I am also using autoregressive model residuals(ar 1, by(rank_category) t(age.months)) .

I am confused if I should be clustering the standard errors at level of app_id or that of rank_category.

Another conceptual doubt that I have is, if I cluster errors at app_id level, it would take care of the serial autocorrelation between different observations for each app_id. However, that was the reasoning behind using the autoregressive model. So, is it necessary to use both approaches together, or is it alright to cluster the errors at rank_category level? To come out clean, clustering at rank_category level gives me favorable results.

```
xtmixed avg_monthly_rating age.months i.promoted##i.rank_category, || app_id : age.months, covariance(unstructured) residuals(ar 1, by(rank_category) t(age.months)) variance mle vce(cluster rank_category)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Edit : It is a panel data with around 11 observations for each of 22,000 apps. The column 'promoted' is a boolean variable which goes from 0 to 1 when a particular app is promoted, staying 1 for all the later observations. What I am interested in is the discontinuous jump/fall that happens in monthly_avg_rating when an app is promoted. I am interacting it with rank_category to check if there is any difference in the magnitude of the jump for different rank categories. There is a big difference when I plot these.

Edit : Cross-listed on statalist.org

Comment: I don't have a complete answer since I don't understand the structure of your data very well. Some advice on what to cluster on [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/176151/7071). Also, clustering allows for arbitrary auto-correlations, whereas AR(1) only allows for a very particular sort.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Thanks. I have added some more information about my data in the edit. Also, as per my understanding, since I am modelling level 2 at app level, shouldn't that take care of hetereoskedasticity at app level?

Comment: You have 11 months of data on 22,000 apps that are nested in rank_categories. How many rank_categories are there?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov There are 3 rank categories.

Comment: Cross-posted at Statalist. Note that it is always polite and usually required to tell folks this so that they do not waste their time.

Comment: That is probably too few groups to cluster at rank category or to have much confidence in the level 3 parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the cross listing protocol.